# How to download a yt playlist with playlist name as folder name?

Tags: yt-dlp

I want to download a yt playlist with playlist name as the folder name and inside the folder name there should be all the videos with their respective video names with video numbers.

I can't figure out the yt-dlp docs.
It is complicated for beginners.
Is there any easy docs for it?

Answer (score 0):

It works.

```
//yt-dlp v2023.11.16

yt -f "bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]" --yes-playlist --write-auto-subs --embed-subs --embed-chapters --embed-thumbnail -o /"path/%(playlist_title)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s" --embed-chapters https://youtube.com/playlist?list=xyz
```